# How to count how many time the code run in python

Tags: python, profiling

I'm building a tool to output how many time the code run in python.  For instance, when the input is

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

The output would be

```
def fib(n):                            21891
    if n <= 1:                         10946
        return n                       10946
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)          8000
fib(20)                                    1
```

The number on the right shows how many time the code run.

What I doing is rewriting the function to

```
def fib(n):
    dic["count_0"] += 1
    if n <= 1:
        dic["count_6"] += 1
        return n
        dic["count_7"] += 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    dic["count_8"] += 1
fib(20)
dic["count_10"] += 1
```

Then handle the edge case like comments or `return` keyword. I wonder any other way to do this without to many hacks like this.

Comment: The if condition is evaluated everytime, not only when it is true, so that number should be the same as total function calls.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a "profiler". Have a look at line_profiler for python https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler